# Android Inner Class (LocationListener) Never Fires

Tags: android, inner-classes, locationlistener

I am using this code to get the GPS coordinates of the Android device. The LocationListener never fires, and I am not sure why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity {

    private LocationManager locmgr = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        // Start the location manager
        locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    } // onCreate

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // grab the location manager service
        locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                onLocationChange);
    } // onResume

    // Start a location listener
    LocationListener onLocationChange = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // This never fires
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {}
    };
} // end MyClass
```

Comment: you have requested the permissions ? Don't know about GPS but as a guess - is it enabled in the device ?

Comment: On my galaxy nexus I had to wait about 4 minutes for the first location on GPS in a new area. as it took FOREVER to lockup with the satellites. food for thought.

Comment: Okay I switched `locmgr.requestLocationUpdates` from `LocationManage.GPS_PROVIDER` to `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` and it is working now - it may have been that the GPS was just taking a long time to get the location.

Comment: if you are inside you will probalby never get updates from just GPS;-)

Comment: Did you finally solve this ? What was the problem ? If you did solve it please add an answer and accept it